# vue.js arrowkey binding issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am in the process of building my first Vue.js project, and I would like to navigate between pages (prev page/next page) through the left and right keyboard arrow keys.

I've created [a simple alert test](https://jsfiddle.net/james_doe/0zuqxeya/) (and attached my code at the bottom of my ask) to demonstrate the problem I'm facing. When using `v-on:click`, the alert method I created works perfectly fine. I've tried using `v-on:keyup`, `v-on:keydown`, and `v-on:keypress`and neither option triggered an alert to indicate the arrowkey functionality was working.

I discovered this [3+ year old thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1250) detailing a similar problem, and one of the comments described the method I'm using as being a working solution since v1.0.0. I've checked [the key modifier documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) of the current version of Vue and it seems as though I am doing everything correctly.

I'm most likely missing something crucial, but after much experimentation and research, I could use some help. Thanks in advance!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    popupLeft: function(){
        alert("You have gone to the previous page");
    },
    
    popupRight: function(){
        alert("You have gone to the next page");
    },
    
    popupClose: function(){
        alert("You have closed this page");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @keyup.left="popupLeft">Prev Page</button>
  <button @keyup.right="popupRight">Next Page</button>
  <button @click="popupClose">Close Page</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. You just need to tab to the appropriate button so that it gets focus. Otherwise it doesn't receive key events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works just as expected.

If you go to JSFiddle of example above and click the button at first and then use arrows - it will call corresponding events.

The reason is that you've added `@keyup` listeners to buttons, meaning, only if `button` element is in focus and `@keyup` event fires - it will be handled.

In order to use arrow navigation, `keyup` (or `keydown` for my preference) event should be handled from `window` or `document`.

To do that, native event listener should be added with component's handlers:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vczgkf3/)

Comment: I understand now, thank you! I was hoping to avoid the additional javascript to get it working, but it looks like there is no way around it. I feel a little less crazy now